# passing paramters using ksoap2 to .net web service, always passes nulls (empty) values

Tags: .net, android, service, ksoap2

I'm having a problem in calling .net web services from android
using ksoap2. The call is executed just fine without parameters, but
when I pass paramters of any type, the web service just recieves a
null value. I tried everything possible but no luck so far. I hope
someone can help,
The client side code is:

```
 public static boolean temp(){
          try { 

           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME_TEMP);
           PopertyInfo p = new PropertyInfo();
           p.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
           p.setName("num");
           p.setValue(5);
           p.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
           request.addProperty(p)  ;
           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11 );
           envelope.dotNet = true;
           envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           AndroidHttpTransport  androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport (URL);
           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_TEMP, envelope);
     .....
             }

     .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just work fine for me in this way...

```
SoapObject requete = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
propertyInfo.name = "value";
requete.addProperty(propertyInfo, 2);

SoapSerializationEnvelope enveloppe = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
enveloppe.dotNet = true;
enveloppe.setOutputSoapObject(requete);
```

My Soap server is a WCF Service. Client is an android emulator using Ksoap..

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and i could resolve it. For resolving it you should consider the following setting:

my url was: "http://"+"MyIP:80/PathTraceWS/SetPathToServer.asmx"
(I showed the url as above because of stackoverflow validation)

Web service action was : SetData

```
    String SOAP_ACTION= "http://"+"tempuri.org/SetData";
    String OPERATION_NAME="SetData";
    String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE="http://"+tempuri.org/";
    String SOAP_ADDRESS="http://"+"192.168.1.54:80/PathTraceWS/SetPathToServer.asmx";
```

I believe if you set the above parameters correctly your problem will resolve. My problems were:

1- to set  WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE to "http://"+"tempuri.org" not to "http://"+"tempuri.org/"

2- If you are calling web service by android mobile emulator you should not use localhost and instead you should use your system IP

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the webservice, try removing `http://` from your namespace name in the webservice (and updating all your references in your java code).  It's not a solution if it's not your own webservice that you're consuming (for that, you could try [this workaround](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/34961-ksoap-blackberry-jde-2.html#post1545885)) but otherwise it seems to work fine.